# Class AB amplifier conduction angle

Tags: amplifier

This is a beginner's theoretical question. I was looking at the figures on this site: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/amp_6.html and noticed that the so called "conducting angle" of a class AB amplifier is given this way:

[image]

It is said to conduct between 180° and 360°. What I don't understand is that the output signal is coming from two transistors, additive. I see that a single trasistor in the pair does not conduct in the full 360° range. But the amplifier as a whole does conduct at any angle right? The transfer function of the amplifier won't be a straight line (obviously), but I don't see where the signal is clipped. Please help me understand.

UPDATE: here is a graph showing two functions:

f(x) = min(-0.6, sin(x))
g(x) = max(0.6, sin(x))

I believe that the response of the whole amp to a sinusoidal input is something like f(x)+g(x)

[image]

Comment: Its not explained very well. That graph shows the operating point of just one transistor of the complementary pair operating in class B.

Comment: Don`t use these tutorial pages. They contain errors. In the shown picture, the input signal is on the Vce axis. Is Vce really the input for an amplifier? A more correct figure is here:http://images.google.de/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.learnabout-electronics.org%2FAmplifiers%2Fimages%2Fclass-AB.gif&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.learnabout-electronics.org%2FAmplifiers%2Famplifiers55.php&h=339&w=259&tbnid=mvqZc2FHT4wsQM%3A&vet=1&docid=6lGRTiHAb1Q0iM&ei=sMhTWM3RN6fAgAab5Iu4BA&tbm=isch&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=967&page=0&start=0&ndsp=34&ved=0ahUKEwjN6bWIx_jQAhUnIMAKHRvyAkcQMwhBKB8wHw&bih=895&biw=1680

Comment: Okay, that page shows a different graph http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Amplifiers/images/class-AB.gif but it is still clipped. It is also for one transistor only, right?

Comment: Yes - of course. Both transistors are active for different times. Both half waves must be superimposed. Note that the correct graph also shows the "cross-over distortions" caused by the lower part of the Ic=f(Vbe) transfer curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the single diagram you post, run away from those web pages.

It seems they've managed to make a simple concept difficult to understand, and got it wrong in the process.  What it appears that diagram is trying to show is how *one* of the transistors operates.  However, what they are showing is class B operation, not class AB.

In class B, each transistor only conducts for exactly half the cycle, as shown.  In class AB, there is a little crossover between the two transistors.  Exactly in the middle, they are both conducting some.  In the diagram you show, point Q should really be moved to the left a little, and the "output signal" biased up a little.

### Added

Yes, your new diagram now shows true class AB behavior.

Comment: I'm sorry, I got the wrong diagram from that website. Replacing now.

Comment: Diagram replaced. So it seems that it is indeed between 180 and 360 degrees, but that is just for one transistor. The question is: will the amplifier as a amplify in 360°? (I guess so?)

Comment: Okay, so the answer is: yes, the class AB amp does amplify signals in 360°, but it is not linear.

Comment: @nag: Each individual transistor is non-linear over the whole signal range, but the whole resulting amplifier is intended to be linear.

Comment: Olin Lathrop - "intended to be linear"??? And what about the cross-over effect? What then is the difference to class-A operation? Can you give a gain value for class AB?

Comment: @LvW: A, B, and AB are intended to do the same thing, which is to amplify the input signal without any distortion.  The details are about tradeoffs under the hood.  Class A has inherently less distortion, so requires less correction that can cause other problems.  Class B is more efficient, but has potential for distortion at the zero crossings, which is hard to get rid of.  Class AB is a compromise between the two.  It is better behaved at the zero crossings, but wastes more power than class B, but not as much as full class A.  All are linear (with some minimal distortion) if done right.

Comment: I am aware of the three options - and the corresponding pros and cons. However, when class-B has considerable distortions and class AB is a "compromise" between A and B, how can you say that AB is intended to be "linear"? For my opinion, it is better to say (and that is the only justification for AB): Class AB operation is a trade-off between "power efficiency" (best is B) and "linearity, resp. THD"  (best is A).

Comment: @LvW: They are all *intended* to be linear.  Class A makes this easier to achieve, and the results are usually a bit better.  We're talking about a fraction of a percent total harmonic distortion.  That is "linear" for most cases, although none is truly linear if by that you mean 0% THD.  Class B and AB are "fixed" usually with more feedback, which has other drawbacks.

Comment: OK - perhaps I did not pay enough attention to the term "intended" you have used. Of course, for designing amplifiers it is always our goal to have the transfer curve "as linear as possible" - knowing that 100% linearity can never be achieved. Nevertheless, I think we should not overlook the fact that the justification for class AB operation is a trade-off between efficiency and linearity.